# Global variable for expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to pass data between functions that may change per request. Is there a way to globally store such details?

My Idea was to have an authCheck function that is handled whenver someone access any routes `/*`.  that function will then check if their token is valid.  If it is, the program continues, if it isnt, then it just stops there.  If the token is valid, I wanted to set a variable for their ID that can be accessible without having to constantly do an SQL query in each function.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use [sessions](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a `use` function that always runs and attach data to `req`, like this example:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // Just an example...
    db.query('SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE dat = ?', [req.cookies.token], function (err, result) {
        // Check token...
        if (err || results.length === 0) {
            next(err || 'Invalid token');
        } else {
            // Set in req obj for other functions to access
            req.token = results[0].dat;
            next();
        }
    });
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // Example render template with token attached...
    res.render('test', {token: req.token}); 
});
```

Comment: When does `app.use` run?

Comment: It is middle-ware, it will *always* run prior to other middle-ware (reference: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use)

Comment: I placed the `app.use` in my root js file, but it doesnt seem to run

Comment: Look at the example on the reference page. It shows a basic logger. That's how it works. Mine is nothing more than an adaptation of that.

Comment: Nevermind, got it to work, needed to put it above `app.use(app.router);`